# Python script to run a program with a set of files in Windows

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have a Windows application that is to be run on a series of input files that I have in a directory.

The sequence of operations is:

1. Goto desired directory
2. Run program on the first input file
3. Goto to relative path where the results are generated
4. Rename and copy the file (program generates with same name) in a desired directory
5. Goto Step 2 and continue the rest of the steps with the next file

I am aware that I can use the import subprocess and use subprocess.call() to run the Windows shell commands. How do I effect all these steps in an efficient way ?

Any tips will be helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
santosh

Comment: Please have a look at the guide [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to provide some example code that you have a particular question about.

Answer (score 0):

From what you described I imagine something like this should work.
Just change the paths and names.

```
import os
import shutil

files = [r"C:\Path\To\File1", r"C:\Path\To\File2"]
new_names = ["new_file1", "new_file2"]


def x(file, new_name):
    program_path = r"C:\Path\To\Program"
    save_path = r"C:\Path\To\Save"
    new_path = r"C:\NewPath\To\Folder"
    os.system("%s -argument %s" % (program_path, file))
    shutil.move(save_path, new_path + '/' + new_name)


y = 0
for file_ in files:
    x(file_, new_names[y])
    y += 1
```

Try to provide what you have done so far so you can get a better answer.